# due to item of which tab, contextual menu was instantiated?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabs, android-contextmenu

In my android application I have 3 tabs. Each of these 3 tabs have got listviews. Now I have registered these listviews for a contextual menu. How do i detect the tab (id or its name) from which the Contextual menu was instantiated? because all the three listviews from the tabs are registered for same contextual menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a tab get selected you can save the current Tab into a variable, then when an item get selected you can use this value.

```
    private String mCurrentTab;

    public MyTabActivity(){

        this.getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId){
                mCurrentTab = tabId;
            }
        });

        .
        .
        .
    }

    public getCurrentTab(){
        return mCurrentTab;
    }
```

Note, that the TabActivity has been deprecated since ICS (4.0) so you may consider, use Fragments instead,

Comment: yes, i am new to android , so i am just learning and trying out few basic things , thanks for your reply !!
can you just hint me on "save the current Tab into a variable"

Comment: Sure, I've added an example